# Difference between \textsc{ciao} and \text{\scshape ciao}

Tags: fonts

I'm wondering if there is any difference between `\textsc{ciao}` and `\text{\scshape ciao}`. I wrote them in Texmaker and it seems that the effect is the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two differences:

1. the `\text` construction in text mode is the same as `\mbox`, so its argument cannot be split across lines or hyphenated;
2. no italic correction is added at the end.

Of course, there's no difference in math mode. Indeed, a command such as `\textsc{...}` in math mode becomes `\text{\scshape ...}`.

Speaking of text mode, the first outlined difference might be what you're actually looking for, but in that case why not using `\mbox` directly?

About the latter outlined difference, it doesn't really show with small caps, but the similar situation with italics should be considered

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\text{\itshape if} test

\textit{if} test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps less impressive, but important, with `\bfseries` and `\textbf` you get

[image]

Comment: Hello @egreg thank you very much for your detailed answer